# Filter files in a folder?

Tags: nautilus, files

How can you filter out files in a given folder by typing in characters into a "filter by" box?  Is there a script or extension that will enable this functionality in Nautilus?

Answer (score 5):

In Natulius press "CTRL + F", and search for '.[extension]'.

For example, to locate all the MP3s in a folder you'd type '.mp3'.

Comment: Can you prevent this from listing the contents of subfolders?

Comment: That does not get you all mp3's it will get you files ending on `.mp3` (subtle but important difference ;) )

Comment: This is true, although you could use the 'by type' to select music. I do not know of a way of filtering only the current folder without resorting to the terminal.

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, then any regular expression.

Sources: [1](https://askubuntu.com/a/98308/12518), [2](https://askubuntu.com/a/504028/12518)

Comment: Annoyingly, in Ubuntu 14.04 at least this only selects _one_ (seemingly random) entry matching the expression.