# How to filter content in the currently opened folder?

Tags: nautilus, files, search

There is one thing I'm missing since I've been forced to move from OSX to Ubuntu.

For OSX there is a wonderful file browser named [Path Finder](http://cocoatech.com/) which has very handy filter function built-in. The search field in the Path Finders upper right corner isn't searching your whole HD, it's not searching in all the sub folders of a given directory (like in Nautilus). It's just filtering the content of the folder you have currently opened without looking in to the subfolders.

Is there something similar (plugin, extension, etc.) available for Nautilus?

Two users have already [asked](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47935/filter-files-in-a-folder) the same [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47431/filter-function-in-file-managers), but the answers obviously missed the point.

Comment: The answer lies in the questions, use Dolphin.

Comment: It's not real filtering, but if you open a folder in Nautilus and then start typing the **first** few letters, the appropriate folder/file will be selected.

Comment: The search feature in the top right corner of Nautilus seems to me to function the way you are asking for... could you describe what it's doing that is different than what you want?  (And/or show some screenshots of what Path Finder does that you are looking for.)

Comment: @JavierRivera What's better about Dolphin?

Comment: Back them it allowed for the feature that the user needed. Right now, default Nautilus has it too, so the comment is pointless.

Comment: it seems the answers this time have missed the point, either that or the Nautilus designers have missed the point and omitted an obviously needed feature?

Answer (score 3):

I think Nautilus should allow the user to filter the contents of a folder as much as wanted, but here's something that might be of use for you:

Press <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> (or **Edit > Select items matching**) and you can filter contents with basic REGEX.

Answer (score 0):

Just like @fader said: Just press search button and there you can choose do you want to search that folder or all files. That folder is selected as default.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As this was the first hit in Google I can add another solution that I ended up with:

Recursive search is default in nautilus(search in subfolders), but I preferred type ahead search(only search in current folder).
In dconf-editor navigate to org > gnome > nautilus > preferences and set the enable-interactive-search value to what you'd like to use.

http://www.webupd8.org/2014/01/nautilus-type-ahead-find-feature.html

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 17.10, which uses gnome 3, when you have an open folder, you go to "Preferences" in the upper menu bar, then "Search & Preview", then "Search in subfolders". You can set that to "never".