# Nautilus how filter every files by extension

Tags: nautilus

I want to filter every mp3 files in certain folder and its sub-folders. I typed *.mp3 in the search box but it is not working.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can hide files others file if not using terminal, but go to view and click to show by file extension

Comment: @Geo do you mean View by type?

Answer (score 8):

Press `Ctrl+S`.

In the appearing dialog you can enter a regex, such as `*.mp3`, in order to **select** all matching file names in the folder itself.

[image: dialog for pattern matching]

Answer (score 7):

You can search/find.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and enter the extension, like `.ogg` and all the files with the extension `.ogg` will be shown, depending on the directories you search in.

It's not quite what you asked for, but it's as close as I can think of.

Comment: Personally, I think it is exactly what was asked for (either that or I didn't understand the question). This is a very fast way to find all the files that include a given string (in this case extension)